# Killing and getting traceback

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL 10.7 and some of my queries are taking a very long time but I don't know what query it is, I know that there is a possibility to kill the process in the middle of it and get a trackback to figure out which query is taking so long. How can I achieve that?

UPDATE:
basically in my App i push a button and it takes too long, so i just want to know what query is taking this much time

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actualy checked now and it's 10.7. I updated my question

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend

Comment: The backtrace will show you where it currently is. Use `strace` (or the equivalent for your operating system) to see the system calls it is issuing. Do you have any reason to suspect that PostgreSQL is not just running your query?

Comment: @JackDorset i'n my app i push a button and there is some kind of query, I want to kill postress and get a trackback i seen this somewhere but can't remember how it's done

Comment: Is that an UPDATE statement or a SELECT query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameI don't know, it can be both

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` to see if it's a statement that is simply slow or a DML statement that is waiting for a lock - but why don't you know what your application is sending to the database? Can't you just debug your application instead? Or turn on logging in the application to see what it's doing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i push button, write ORM function is called and there is no delay, but after that, there is loading screen for 15 seconds, so there is definitely something going on, but i don't know what it is. as I can debug only until write is finished.

Comment: As I said: start checking `pg_stat_activity` -  and  turn on logging in your obfuscation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below hits the high points here. The below should give details as to what's up.

```
 create function python_version()
returns text
language plpythonu
as $$

import sys
import traceback

try:
    return sys.version
except:
    error = sys.exc_info()[0]
    details = traceback.format_exc()
    plpy.error('%s: %s' % ( error, details ) )
$$;
```